# Conga conditional statement using rowcount

Tags: conditional-statements, salesforce, statements

I'm using Conga with Salesforce and am trying to build a conditional statement that will hide/show content within a word document template. I'm struggling with getting the sytanx correct.

Below is a couple of lines I'm testing in the template and followed by an image showing the results. Note that {{RowCount:GETAA}} is returning the expected value of 1, however, the "great than" or "less than" text is not rendering correctly.

- Test 1: {{IF{{RowCount:GETAA}}>0 “greater than” “less than” }}
- Test 2: {IF{{RowCount:GETAA}}>0 “greater than” “less than” }

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to put a space in between IF and {{RowCount:GETAA}}?

So  *{IF {{RowCount:GETAA}}>0 “greater than” “less than” }*